# Speaker equalization for white noise

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency-spectrum, filter-design, equalization

I need a speaker to play broadband white noise for my scientific application. I would like to know whether my relative naive implementation is correct or not. The [speakers I use](https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/13-8-2mm-Cell-phone-Speakers-For-Nokia-N86-X6-00-E71-E72-E73-E5-00/1260730_32690466249.html) have a large frequency range but the response is not flat, so I need to equalize the sound. What I do is the following:

Software used: Matlab 2016a with Psychtoolbox 3 (latest version) for minimum latency playback.

Hardware used: Windows 10 PC (i5, 8 GB RAM), ASUS soundcard (192 KHz), National Instruments DAS card (250 kHz), profesional microphone, speakers, soundproof box.

- First I generate a `randn` array of a desired length, with the sampling frequency of the soundcard. The normally distributed random values are properly truncated so they don't exceed +1 or -1, which is the maximum range of the input signal, but also in a way that the gaussian distribution is minimally disrupted.
- Then I play the sound through the speaker and I record it with the mic and the NI card (at the card's maximum sampling frequency). I discard the beginning and the end of the signal to ensure that I have something stable, and I divide it in chunks of equal length (I discard whatever reminder they may be). After that I calculate the fft for each chunk, I obtain the absolute value, and I average it for all the chunks. As expected, the amplitude profile is not flat.
- Finally, I generate a new signal in the same way as I did the first time (I could reuse the original, I guess) and I obtain its fft. Then I multiply it point by point with the inverse of the average absolute fft of the recorded signal from the last step, properly interpolated so it has the same number of frequency points, and reflected at the middle frequency so the symmetry is respected. I take the ifft and thus it becomes my equalized signal. When I play and record it, I observe indeed that the frequency response is much flatter than the original signal.

I posted [another question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/43818/speaker-calibration-for-broadband-white-noise-between-5-and-20-khz) that describes the process more extensively. Here I omitted many details to focus just on the equalization part.

Comment: the google shortlink (whyever you use a shortlinker?) is 404 not found!

Comment: huh, I'm a bit surprised. In the sense of minimizing efforts, why the aftermarket telephone speakers? Feels like a mismatch to the "scientific application" – these things aren't really known for linearity, are they?

Comment: As far as I've seen they are linear, stable and durable. The size is key for us, and it's difficult to find something similar. The very few options provided from scientific oriented vendors are essentially the same product but they are charged 20 times more. We were actually recommended from one of the people that we used to manage the purchases that we should just buy those cellphone speakers because they perform the same. Not the 'scientific' speakers of that side were actually discontinued.

Comment: I meant 'Now', not 'Not', and 'size' not 'side' in the last sentence, sorry.

Comment: It would be good to know the length of your signal , and the length of the chunks. You should apply a window function to the chunks, if you are not already.  Also you should be suspicious of low-energy bins that result in very large correction gains. These response dips are usually caused by room reflections, and you can't fix reflections with a filter. Most people apply a smoothing function to the gain vector.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Bob . The length of the signal is 30 seconds, and the length of the chunks are 25 ms. I didn't mention it in the post, but I'm only interested in the frequencies from 5 to 20 kHz, the rest gets filtered out. Also I do apply some smoothing to the gain vector.

Now, I have to admit I don't understand the purpose of applying the window to the chunks. I thought that just by taking the fft of each chunk I would obtain the amplitudes of the frequency components. I would really appreciate if you could explain me more carefully this point.

Comment: To obtain a chunk you are effectively multiplying by a rectangular window. Since multiplication in the time domain is convolution in the frequency domain, you are convolving the spectrum with a sinc function which has very poor attenuation of other frequencies. A window function like Hanning has a slightly wider main lobe but much better attenuation of other frequencies.

Comment: I see! And how do I choose the length and shape of the window? Is there any rule of thumb that I could apply? Should I consider overlapping chunks as well? Also, is there a way to know what frequencies are being most affected with the rectangular window? 
Sorry, those are a lot of questions! :)